# airmon-ng start wlan0 problems

Tags: kali-linux

I was trying to `aircrack-ng`, but the problem everytime I

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

`prism0` shows up not `mon0`. What to do?

```
root@kali:~# airmon-ng start wlan0
PHY Interface Driver Chipset
phy0 wlan0 wl Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
    (experimental wl monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]prism0)
```

Comment: Reposting the same thing ( http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303615/i-was-trying-to-aircrack-ng-but-the-problem-everytime-i-airmon-ng-start-wlan0-pr ) won't bring you any positive attention and both questions will probably get closed for lack of details anyways.  Focus on improving the question instead of repeating it.

Answer (score 1):

***Overview***

Although you can use `airmon-ng` to put an interface into monitor mode, you can also do it using `iwconfig`. Make sure you have root privilages!

***Put wlan0 into monitor mode:***

```
ifconfig wlan0 down

iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor

ifconfig wlan0 up
```

***Kill process that could interfere:***

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

Now you can run an `airodump-ng` scan with the interface into monitor mode by running the command `airodump-ng wlan0`

***Put interface back into managed mode when finished:***

```
ifconfig wlan0 down

iwconfig wlan0 mode managed

ifconfig wlan0 up

service network-manager restart
```

Comment: when my interface is in monitor mode, no packets are transferred/captured, it loses connection to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. My chipset was RTL8812AU.
You just need to do the following-

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

After that, make sure you are disconnected to the internet, because your WiFi adapter is now monitoring networks. In my case I was doing `service NetworkManager restart` which again connected me to the internet. Don't do it.

Then run,

```
airmon-ng start yourinterface
```

Check if monitor mode is enabled by doing `iwconfig`
Now use airodump-ng.

Answer (score 0):

As long as wlan0 is put into monitor mode, it is working fine. It could be called wlan0mon or mon0 or prism0 as it is called here, just like how a Wi-Fi card could be called wlan0 or ath0, or almost anything else. Either I don't understand what you are asking or you don't have a problem. Just remember to use prism0 in future commands like airodump-ng.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using inbuilt wifi adaptor of pc. I was also facing this problem. You better use a external USB WiFi adaptor which supports monitor mode. This could help you to send and receive the packets.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, would you mind explaining why an on-board adaptor would have that problem, and an external one not? Attaching an external adaptor may not be an option for all readers finding this post ...